# Keyboard Setup Assistant triggered at every boot with Logitech MX Mechanical Mini

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, macos

I recently purchased a Logitech MX Mechanical Mini keyboard. The keyboard has an "easy switch" feature so it can be paired with up to 3 devices and toggling between them is handled through a set of keyboard shortcuts.

Whenever I boot up and log into my Mac Mini (2018, Ventura v13.5.1), the keyboard setup assistant is launched. Not a huge inconvenience, but annoying.

Can anything be done to stop this from happening since the device is "paired" over bluetooth with the machine even if it's through the so called "easy switch" feature Logitech provides on the keyboard?